# TCL Regexp Strip off Upper Case Letters and Underscores

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a variable that is always given a string such as:

```
A_GPH_UNITSTESTSFRAMEWORK21_0_0
```

This string is assigned to a variable called `$test`. I am trying to figure out how I can strip off the `A_GPH_UNITSTESTSFRAMEWORK` from `$test` as this will always be the same. The numbers will always be different but in the same format with `_`.

**Edit:**

This seems to work fine using :

```
regsub {^[A-Z_A-Z]+} $test "" noletters
```

Comment: Using `string range` instead, if it's always the same?

Comment: @Jerry I think I have got this to work using this regsub {^[A-Z_A-Z]+} $test "" noletters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for that. Use string methods:

```
set result [string range $test 25 end]
```

should be what you use.

Or if you have the repeating part stored in a variable:

```
set same "A_GPH_UNITSTESTSFRAMEWORK"
set result [string range $test [string len $same] end]
```

Answer (score 0):

To strip *leading* capitals and underscores, do either:

```
set result [regsub {^[A-Z_]+} $test ""]
```

or:

```
set result [string trimleft $test "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_"]
```

Alternatively, to remove a fixed string, do:

```
set result [string map {A_GPH_UNITSTESTSFRAMEWORK ""} $test]
```

Comment: I'd usually use the `regsub` but then I know REs well…